# Get specific columns from scipy csr_matrix

Tags: scipy

I have a sparse matrix which if I print looks like this:

```
  (0, 1773)     0.626247271075
  (0, 1604)     0.626247271075
  (0, 1515)     0.299755787345
  (0, 660)      0.354647964743
  (1, 2379)     0.206542018824
  (1, 2159)     0.158175640686
```

There are in fact over 2000 columns, but as it is a sparse matrix only this is printed. I want to get the values of what looks like the second column, sorted by the last column, so like this:

```
  x: 1604     y: 0.626247271075
  x: 660      y: 0.354647964743
  x: 1515     y: 0.299755787345
  x: 2379     y: 0.206542018824
  x: 2159     y: 0.158175640686
```

The Scipy documentation is not very clear to me, how do I access these columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the non-zero indices using [scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero)

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
A = csr_matrix([[1,2,0],[0,0,3],[4,0,5]])
print(A.nonzero()) 

(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2]))
```